# jquery xml parse issue

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

Having issues with my XML not parsing correctly. I cant see my data from my xml. My xml is correct as well. Does anyone see anything that could be the problem.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {       
          $.get('http://www.mytasteofitaly.com/menu/menu-1a.xml', function(data) {
                $(data).find('menu').each(function() {
                var $main = $(this);
                $main.find('menu').each(function() {
                   var $menu = $(this);
                   var id = $menu.attr('id');
                   var head = $menu.find('menuhead').text();

                   var html = '<div class="mainmen" id="main_' + id + '">';
                   html += '<table class="menus"><th><h1>' + head + '</h1></th>';
                   $menu.find('menuitem').each(function() {

                   var name = $menuitem.find('menuname').text();
                   var desc = $menuitem.find('menudesc').text();
                   var price = $menuitem.find('price').text();
                   var desprice = $menuitem.find('price2des').text();
                   var price2 = $menuitem.find('price2').text();

                    html += '<tr class="menu_item">';
                    html += '<td class="h-menu">' + name + '</td>';
                    html += '<td class="d-menu">' + desc + '</td>';
                    html += '<td class="price">' + price + '</td>';
                    html += '<td class="desprice">' + desprice + '</td>';
                    html += '<td class="price2">' + price2 + '</td>' + '</tr>';

                    $('#menuitem').append($(html));
                });
           });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not making a cross domain call?

Comment: And you did of course `console.log($(data));` to see that the jQuery object returned is what you think it is ?

Comment: I am a bit of a noob how would i setup console.log?

Comment: Ok in the console it is loading the xml.

Comment: Does it show any errors in the console ?

Comment: The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must to be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.  Just that

Comment: well i figured it somewhat out. It loads and shows my data but now my output is showing divs for everyitem.